# Delete button on my listview is not working as it is supposed to

Tags: java, android, listview

so I was wanting to have a delete button on each item of my list, so that when that button is pressed, I want that particular list item to be completely removed. However, when I try to do this, it doesn't work. Moreover, If I click on the delete icon twice, the app crashes.
This is the code for my list adapter :

```
    package com.example.taskmasterv3;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SubtaskAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<subtask> {


    private final Context context;
    private ArrayList<subtask> values;


    public SubtaskAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<subtask> list) {

        //since your are using custom view,pass zero and inflate the custom view by overriding getview
    super(context, 0 , list);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = list;
}



@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    //check if its null, if so inflate it, else simply reuse it
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.subtask_item, parent, false);
    }

    //use convertView to refer the childviews to populate it with data
    TextView tvSubtaskName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSubtaskName);
    ImageView ivPri = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivPri);
    ImageView ivTime = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivTime);
    ImageView ivDelete = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivDelete);

    tvSubtaskName.setText(values.get(position).getSubtaskName());

    if (values.get(position).isPriHigh()) {
        ivPri.setImageResource(R.drawable.priority_high);
    } else if (values.get(position).isPriMed()) {
        ivPri.setImageResource(R.drawable.priority_med);
    } else if (values.get(position).isPriLow()) {
        ivPri.setImageResource(R.drawable.priority_low);
    }

    if (values.get(position).isTimeMore()) {
        ivTime.setImageResource(R.drawable.time_symbol_more);
    } else if (values.get(position).isTimeMed()) {
        ivTime.setImageResource(R.drawable.time_symbol_med);
    } else if (values.get(position).isTimeLess()) {
        ivTime.setImageResource(R.drawable.time_symbol_less);
    }


    // Delete button for subtasks (NOT WORKING)

    ivDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            values.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    //return the view you inflated
    return convertView;
}





//to keep adding the new subtasks try the following
public void addANewSubTask(subtask newSubTask){
    ArrayList<subtask> newvalues = new ArrayList<>(this.values);
    newvalues.add(newSubTask);
    this.values = newvalues;
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

}

Comment: Does removeAt works for you?

Comment: I don't see any such option. The ones I see are remove , removeAll , removeIf. I am using android studio...

Answer (score 0):

Using ListView in this way is very bad and memory heavy due to continue creation of OnClickListener and resolving View IDs using findViewById().
The less invasive solution is to use a ViewHolder that caches all View IDs and the ClickListener:

```
public class SubtaskAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<subtask> {

    private final LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    public SubtaskAdapter(@NonNull final Context context, @NonNull final List<subtask> values) {
        super(context, R.layout.subtask_item, values);
        this.mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        private int mPosition = -1;
        private final TextView tvSubtaskName;
        private final ImageView ivPri;
        private final ImageView ivTime;
        private final ImageView ivDelete;
        private final View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener;
        private ViewHolder(@NonNull final ArrayAdapter<subtask> arrayAdapter, @NonNull final View convertView) {
            this.tvSubtaskName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSubtaskName);
            this.ivPri = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivPri);
            this.ivTime = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivTime);
            this.ivDelete = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivDelete);
            this.mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(final View v) {
                    arrayAdapter.remove(arrayAdapter.getItem(ViewHolder.this.mPosition));
                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            };
            this.ivDelete.setOnClickListener(this.mOnClickListener);
        }
        private void setPosition(final int position) { this.mPosition = position; }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull final ViewGroup parent) {
        final View cParentView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        if (cParentView != null) return cParentView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = this.mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.subtask_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(this, convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.setPosition(position);
        
        final subtask cCurrentSubtask = getItem(position);

        holder.tvSubtaskName.setText(cCurrentSubtask.getSubtaskName());

        if (cCurrentSubtask.isPriHigh()) {
            holder.ivPri.setImageResource(R.drawable.priority_high);
        } else if (cCurrentSubtask.isPriMed()) {
            holder.ivPri.setImageResource(R.drawable.priority_med);
        } else if (cCurrentSubtask.isPriLow()) {
            holder.ivPri.setImageResource(R.drawable.priority_low);
        }

        if (cCurrentSubtask.isTimeMore()) {
            holder.ivTime.setImageResource(R.drawable.time_symbol_more);
        } else if (cCurrentSubtask.isTimeMed()) {
            holder.ivTime.setImageResource(R.drawable.time_symbol_med);
        } else if (cCurrentSubtask.isTimeLess()) {
            holder.ivTime.setImageResource(R.drawable.time_symbol_less);
        }
        
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

You do not need to use an internal "values" to hold all Items, you can use "ArrayAdapter.add()" and other similar methods (remove(), getItem(), getCount(), etc..) after you created the ArrayAdapter passing initial Items Array/List.

**EDIT**: To add items to the ArrayAdapter you need to save ArrayAdapter instance and then call its "add()" method.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    @Nullable
    private SubtaskAdapter mSubtaskAdapter = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mSubtaskAdapter = new SubtaskAdapter(this, subtask_items);
    }
    private boolean addSubtaskToList(@Nullable final subtask newSubtask) {
        if ((mSubtaskAdapter == null) || (newSubtask == null)) return false;
        mSubtaskAdapter.add(newSubtask);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I am having trouble in implementing this in my current code. I am still new to programming. Could you please help me out a little here

Comment: Also, the delete functionality is still not working for me

Comment: I added final comment in my Answer. You don't need "values" inside the ArrayAdapter, but you can create the ArrayAdapter by passing initial Array/List and then use its own add(), addAll(), remove(), getCount(), getItem(), etc... methods (an Internal ArrayList<T> is used by ArrayAdapter itself)

Comment: Okay. So now I am using this : SubtaskAdapter.this.remove() , but inside the parenthesis after remove, it says I have to put in a subtask object. How do I refer to the list item which the user is trying to delete here?

Comment: Yes it's a bit strange but it should be done using "SubtaskAdapter.this.remove(SubtaskAdapter.this.getItem(position))" in your case. I don't know why the Adapter doesn't exposed a simple "remove(index)" method.....

Comment: Yeah... Works fine now. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Wait lol. Now there is an issue. The delete icon does delete a list item, but not the particular list item on which I clicked the delete button on. It automatically deletes the last item in the list. Can you please help out with this as well?

Comment: I'm not using Android Studio now from my mobile phone, so I could have made mistakes in previous code. Now I fixed OnClick() method.

Comment: Actually I am still using my version of the code, and not what you sent as I couldn't understand how to implement it. But, the delete function is deleting the last item in the list, irrespective of where I click the delete button. Any solution for this?

Comment: Your code cannot work well because all OnClickListeners are created on each getView() call, so when you delete a Position the other rows (that are still visible without scroll) have previous OnClickListeners that are pointing to wrong/changed Position(s). In this situation it could be possible to call "value.remove(..)" of a Position that doesn't exists more even if its OnClickListener was holding its Position Index reference.

Comment: Yes, but the thing is, when I am pasting the code given by you, I am getting a lot of errors, that I am having trouble solving...

Comment: I completed the Class java file. If some words are in RED is because you need to ATL+ENTER on each word and IMPORT it. Currenly code is complete and is working.

Comment: Could you please also tell me what I should write instead of values in the 'Add a new subtask' method (given in my code in the end)...

Comment: You just need to save "new ArrayAdapter<>(context, values)" result and use it doing "newArrayAdapter.add(subtask);"

Comment: I am sorry, but I am unable to understand.

Comment: I've modified my answerd. It seems you have very_low/basic knowledge of Java even for this kind of basic procedures....I suggest you to start using Java from the base and when you feel enough good then proceed with something more difficult. (just my 2 cents)

Comment: lol I agree. Actually, I was quite proficient with my basics. Then came exams. 2 months later. I'm here. Wasn't able to complete this project then, so am doing it now. Thanks to you man!

Comment: If you like my answer don't forget to Accept it ;)

Answer (score 0):

change `values.remove(position);` to `values.remove(values.get(position));`

Comment: Yeah that seems to be fixed now, but the issue I am facing now is that the delete button automatically deletes the last item of the list, and not that particular item that I want it to delete. Any fix for this?